# Is there a way to refer bean's property (both getter and setter) in Javadoc?

Tags: java, hyperlink, javabeans, javadoc

Suppose I have a class with bean's property `sum`, which is implemented with setter `void setSum(double value)` and getter `double getSum()`.

Is it possible to refer this by single link in javadoc? Suppose I wish to describe some properties in class' preamble. For example, something like this:

```
/**
 * A Value class is a bunch of aggregation values
 * 
 * {@beanlink #sum} - sum of all values (hypothetic way)
 * 
 * {@link #getSum()} - sum of all values (conventional way)
 * 
 */
```

Comment: what do you mean by single link? The way you are doing it now is correct.

Comment: Is there `{@beanlink}` syntax in Javadoc??

Comment: Where should the link point to? The setter or the getter? It is only unabiguous for read-only or write-only properties. Or should it create two links?

Comment: @his I have no idea. I was expecting solution exists. `Javadoc` could create separate entries for properties for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any `@beanlink` kind of tag in javadoc comments. See a full list of allowed tag [javadoc of javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags) ;)

There is a [`-tag`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#tag) option that can be used to create custom tags. But that won't perfectly fit for your solution, i.e. creating links.